# How to get a path of an image and trim it?

Tags: vb.net, path, filepath

I'm trying to get image upload working . So far I have this :

```
        Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim strPath As String = ""
        dlg.Filter = "PNG(*.png;)|*.png;"
        dlg.ShowDialog()

        Dim fileName As String = dlg.FileName.Trim
        Dim ftpDirectory As String = ""
        If fileName <> "" Then
            If fileName.Contains("[") AndAlso fileName.Contains("].png") Then
                MessageBox.Show("The file you have selected is on the FTP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else

                strPath = dlg.FileName.ToString

                End If

                If button = 1 Then
                txtSmallDealOneImg.Text = strPath
```

However the strPath returns the whole path to image file for example C:/website/Images/page1/photo1.png

How do I trim the output so that it only shows /Images/Page1/photo1.png ?

The images are in different folders so I would need to trim everything thats followed by /images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to remove the static "C:/website" from the path?

Then you could simply use

```
If strPath.StartsWith("C:/website") Then
    txtSmallDealOneImg.Text = strPath.Substring("C:/website".Length)
End If
```

If you instead want to remove everything before the Image-subdirectory you can use:

```
Dim imageIndex = strPath.IndexOf("/Images/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
If imageIndex >= 0 Then
    txtSmallDealOneImg.Text = strPath.Substring(imageIndex)
End If
```

Comment: what if images are in different folder ei. D:/Other/Images , is there any way to make it more generic for example trim anything before /iamges

Comment: @user3845868: you haven't mentioned that in your question, have you? What are the rules, what is the logic? Do you want everything starting from `Images/...`?

Comment: I know i havent, my bad. Its a massive system I'm working on and there are hundreds of different folders with images , so I would want to get the path that starts at /images/.....

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i want ! :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a generic method that strips away the physical root folder of your web site you could try something like this

```
Public Function GetURLFromAbsolutePath(ByVal absPath As String) As String
     Dim baseSitePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
     Dim url As String = String.Format("{0}", absPath.Replace(baseSitePath, "") _ 
                                                      .Replace("\", "/"))

     Return url
End Function
```